# error while copying std::map defined in a class

Tags: c++, copy, friend

I have a class with a `std::map` used as a container. I want to add a function to copy the map between two objects. Since the map was declared as a private member of the class, I need a friend function to do so. Here is my code:

```
class Data;
void copyData(Data &, Data &);

class Data
{
  private:
    map<int, int> _data;

  public:
    friend void copyData(Data &, Data&);
};

void copyData(Data &a, Data &b)
{
  std::copy(a._data.begin(), a._data.end(), b._data.begin());
}

main()
{
   // initialization here
   Data A, B;
   copyData(A, B);
}
```

But there are many warnings while compiling with mingw32. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a copy constructor?  And, passing b by value into copyData doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And we shouldn't have to guess what warnings your compiler gave you. Provide them. Also, your title says warning, your posts says error. Which is it?

Comment: your map declaration has no type !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::map<K,V>::value_type` is defined as `std::pair<const K,V>`.  This ensures that `std::map<K,V>::iterator` objects can't be used to assign to the key (or else you could use this to break the container invariants).

This means that map iterators don't satisfy the `OutputIterator` concept requirements and you can't use them as the third parameter of the `std::copy()` function.  On the same note, there are lots of situations that would make this code break anyways, such as if one map has more associations than the other.

Besides, there is a much easier way to write your function:

```
void copyData(Data &a, Data &b)
{
  b._data = a._data;
}
```